# Powershell "Canot index into a null aray"

Tags: powershell, conditional, if-condition

I have a powershell script which works but at the same time it throws this error.

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At D:\PowerShell\Items\Update_a_Field.ps1:10 char:69
+     if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $List.ContentTypes[ <<<< "Company Standard"])
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Exterran Standard:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

here is the powershell

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$siteURL = "https://inside.nov.hou/CORP/STD"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{
  foreach($list in $web.Lists) 
  {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $List.ContentTypes["Company Standard"])
    {   
        foreach ($item in $list.Items)
        {
            #if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") # DO NOT USE THIS LINE
            if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -eq "None")
            {
                 # write-host $item.File.CheckedOutByUser
                #if($item.File.CheckedOutByUser -like "SHAREPOINT\system")
                #{
                    <#if($item.File.Versions) # -ne $item.File.VersionText)
                    {
                        write-host $item.id "-" $item.Name " - " $item.Vesion " - " $item.VersionText                       
                    }
                    #>
            #}
            #foreach($version in $item.Versions) 
            #{ 
                #if($version.Level -eq "Draft")

                if($item["_UIVersionString"] -ne $item["VersionText"])
                {
                #if($item["Name"] -eq "COM-PRC-0003.docx")
                #{
                    write-host $item.Name " - " $item["VersionText"] " - " $item["_UIVersionString"]
                    $item["VersionText"] = $item["_UIVersionString"]
                    $item.SystemUpdate()
                #   write-host $item.Name " - " $item["VersionText"] " - " $item["_UIVersionString"]
                #   write-host $item.Title $item.Versions[0].VersionLabel
                #   write-host $item.Versions[0].VersionLabel
                #   $item.File.ReleaseLock($item.File.LockId)
                #   $item.file.UndoCheckOut()

                #}
                }   

            }
        }
    }
  }
$web.Dispose()
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: You're saying you get the expected results from the script, other than the error message appearing?

Comment: It's almost like your list doesn't have any SiteContents. Can you add the following before your IF condition that's causing an issue? `if(!$list.ContentTypes){ Write-Host $($list.Title), $($list.DefaultViewUrl) }`. This should let you know if the list's attribute "ContentTypes" doesn't have any value, and what the list and relative url is.

Comment: yes the update command executes for the correct records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you have some document libraries that don't have any content types. To me that seems like an odd behaviour. It's that, or PowerShell doesn't exit the conditional statement after `$list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"` is `$false` and you have other types of lists that don't have content types.

You said that you get the expected result, so you can just screen for "null content types" by modifying your conditional statement to below:

```
if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and 
   $list.ContentTypes -and
   $list.ContentTypes["Company Standard"])
{   
    # ...
}
```

This checks to make sure the field exists and is not `$null`, then continues the execution.

---

As we were unable to figure out the issue, exactly, you could just mute it with an `$ErrorActionPreference` call. It's bad practice, imo, but it does work.

```
$prevErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference 
$ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue
if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $List.ContentTypes["Company Standard"])
{  
    $ErrorActionPreference = $prevErrorActionPreference
    # ...
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $prevErrorActionPreference
```

The `$ErrorActionPreference` is a special variable that's referenced when an error occurs. You can use the text equivalent (ie `"SilentlyContinue" instead of the .NET Enum). So for just the if-condition it should mute the error, then get reverted to the previous statement.

The call to return to the previous was in case the if-condition is skipped.

Comment: Issue still stands. Let me do more tinkering and see if it helps.

Comment: @RubyTrustit Is the error happening on every Document Library?

Comment: I think it's tapping on hidden libraries because I put write-host $list.Title and those 3 errors are in the middle of M and O. It may be hidden Nintex document libraries which starts with N.

Comment: @RubyTrustit You could try to see if `!list.Hidden` works, instead of "!$list.ContentTypes" in my above answer.

Comment: tried variety !($list.Hidden) or $list.Hidden -eq $False but no luck. Dont worry it's really not a big deal. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @RubyTrustit Ok. I added in my answer a way to mute the IF condition. It should only mute the IF condition, and nothing else.

Comment: cool. let me try the mute code and i will let you know. thanks again

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project.